# Restrict access to endpoints using SecurityFilterChain in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

How to allow only hello endpoint to allow authorization (give default login screen) and for bye endpoint I should see 401/403 error.

I am using Spring Boot v 2.7.1

When I click http://localhost:8080/bye, I should not be able to call it.

MySecurityConfig.java

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin();
        // http.httpBasic();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello").authenticated();
        return http.build();
    }

//    @Bean
//    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
//        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
//        UserDetails userDetails = User.withUsername("john")
//                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("12345")).authorities("READ").build();
//        userDetailsManager.createUser(userDetails);
//        return userDetailsManager;
//    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello from Spring Security";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/bye")
    public String bye() {
        return "Bye";
    }
}
```

AuthenticationProvider.java

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if ("john".equals(username) && "12345".equals(password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, Arrays.asList());
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Username or password");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `/bye` does not defined by any `authorizeRequests()` and any URL that does not have such authorisation rule means there are no need to have any authorisation checking on it and thus it can always be accessed.

You have to explicitly configure a rule to block any access to it by :

```java
 @Bean
 SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin();
        http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/hello").authenticated()
           .antMatchers("/bye").denyAll();
        return http.build();
 }
```

Note that all other URLs beside `/hello` and `/bye` can also be accessed. So a good strategy is that we would normally add a rule in the last to block all the access to all the remaining URLs for better security :

```java
 @Bean
 SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin();
        http.authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/hello").authenticated()
           .antMatchers("/bye").denyAll()
           .anyRequest().denyAll();
        return http.build();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring security 6.1 or above:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable) // If required
            .cors(withDefaults()) // If required
            .authorizeHttpRequests((rm) -> rm
                    .requestMatchers(
                            "/hello"
                    ).authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().denyAll()
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```